# Getting an specific field of a model with a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

If i have this queryset:

```
z = Bets.objects.filter(match_id=request.POST['match']).filter(~Q(team_id=request.POST['team']))
```

How can i get the match_id or team_id?

If i do

> `print z`

it shows me the unicode that i have in the model, i want for example

> `print z.match_id`

but i getting 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'match_id'. match_id is a ForeignKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop through the queryset and print the field of found instances of `Bet` model:

```
for bet in z:
    print bet.match_id
```

If there is can be only one object that matches the criteria then you can use the `get()` or `first()` methods of queryset:

```
bet = z.first()
if bet:
    print bet.match_id
```